# How to redirect if a background request is still being executed

Tags: redirect, actions, wp-redirect

I am using the [Woocommerce Waitlist](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-waitlist/) plugin to allow users to subscribe to product waitlists.
After subscribing to a waitlist I want to redirect the user to another page to complete a form.
I am using the `wcwl_after_add_user_to_waitlist` action, which I found in the [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-waitlist/)like this:

```
add_action( 'wcwl_after_add_user_to_waitlist', 'redirect_to_waitlist_form', 30, 2);
function redirect_to_waitlist_form( $wc_product, $wp_user ) {
   wp_redirect( 'https://teszt.motorozzvelunk.hu/jelentkezes-tura-varolistara/' );
   exit;
}
```

The problem is that the page doesn't redirect I guess because something in the background is happening. I can see a pending progress bar on the page and nothing happens.

[image: progress bar]

Comment: Hi, welcome to [wordpress.se]. As a rule, many in the community consider questions about third-party plugins (such as woocommerce) off-topic so you might notice some down-votes and answers may be slow if they come at all. Have you tried asking the plugin author? You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).